# custom taxonomy not displaying

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I created a custom taxonomy like so:

```
function my_taxonomies_custom() {
      $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Post Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Post Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Post Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Post Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Post Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Post Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Post Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Post Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Post Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Post Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Post Categories' ),
      );
      $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'custom_category',
            'with_front' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true ,
        ),
      );
      register_taxonomy( 'custom_category', 'post_type_slug', $args );  
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_custom', 0 );
```

With a custom category through the admin called `postcat`. From my understanding I should be able to now go to the `URL http://example.com/custom_category/postcat` and this will use the `category.php` page to display a list of pages in the category. When I go to this URL though all I get is a page that says "Not found. Sorry, but your request could not be completed."

Comment: Sorry to ask such a newb question: did you reset your permalinks after?

Comment: Sure did. If I use a plugin to add custom taxonomies to the side bar it cant even find any. Like this one is not being saved even though I can see it.

Comment: does your actual code contain a valid post type in place of `post_type_slug`? did you assign the category to any posts? does your normal post permalink structure contain anything static (setting `with_front` to true will prepend that value if that's the case)?

Comment: `category.php` template file is only for core categories taxonomy. The equivalent for custom taxonomies is `taxonomy.php`. See [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for more information. Anyway, the template file used doesn't seem to be the source of your problem. Follow Milo's suggestions.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @cybmeta. It was that I didint have a taxonomy.php file. I was assuming it would use the category.php file. Is there any good images or resources that explain the hierarchy in a simple way?

Comment: I've edited the comment with a link to the template hierarchy documentation.

Comment: @cybmeta if you post your answer as an answer and not a comment I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I thought it couldn't be an answer because there always the `index.php` template file as fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`category.php` template file is only for core categories taxonomy. The equivalent for custom taxonomies is `taxonomy.php`. See [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for more information.